# Refreshing a particular div content using javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I have a JQuery div element. It displays a picture on the screen. The image is stored in the device memory and is being replaced in continuous interval (with same file name)

Once the image is displayed It's stuck there, I want it to load the latest image ( saved on the memory) by itself when ever I visit this div back in any given time.

Im using javascript to develop this App.

Any little help is appreciated.

**[update]**
This is my code, just the standard way to display the image.
`<img src="/storage/emulated/0/Images/1.png" width="128" height="128">`

The image 1.png will be replaced in regular intervals. I want this to be updated on the screen.

Comment: So what have you tried already? Show your code, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Are you using some framework like Ionic etc?

Comment: Im not using any frameworks. Just the regular JQuery Mobile and javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since cordova camera plugin just allow user to select a image to view/edit or click a image then we can use cordova file plugin to create a functioning gallery app.

add cordova file plugin to your project:

> **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file**

Then create a handler to provide you the path of the images(Syntax):

> window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function
>   (dirEntry) {
>       console.log('file system open: ' + dirEntry.name);
>       var isAppend = true;
>       createFile(dirEntry, "fileToAppend.txt", isAppend); }, onErrorLoadFs);

For details of this plugin:https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

You can download test gallery app showing images from **DCIM/Camera** folder(default) into html **img tag** onto user screen:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8vJcyO8_PK9R1k4STUyaEJQS1k

Answer (score 1):

What you get from sdcard is a **FILE_URI** object such as (file://storage/emulated/0/Images/1.png) or you get **DATA_URL** object which is just the Base64 converted string of above.The html img tag accept **FILE_URI** and **DATA_URL** directly.

Comment: I can see the file as an image in the storage. 
Can you tell me a possible way to solve my problem?

Comment: Please note that you have to get the FILE_URI or DATA_URL of that image and put in img tag as:<img src="file://storage/emulated/0/Images/1.png"> and image will be shown.You can get image using cordova **camera plugin** with method:navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, [ cameraOptions ] );

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im completely new to this.
And sorry for the late response . 

So I just need to add `file://` to the `<img >` tag? Or do something more ?

Comment: I just went though the camera plugin. So here we need to use the camera to capture the image or the local image browser to select the image to get the location? Im trying to display the image without making the user to select it. How can I do that?Can you help me ?