# cordova-plugin-file to play video file from extSD

Tags: android, html, cordova, video, cordova-plugin-file

I am needing to have my cordova wrapped html show a picture and run a video file located off the root of the external SD.  There did not seem to be a place to ask these questions on the git hub for the [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/tree/master#where-to-store-files).

A)  I am not sure I understand what path to use in 2 B&C below in order to accomplish this if the files are in those two sub directories off the root?

B)  Are ALL those values in 3 B necessary if all I need is access to the ext SD?

Here is what I know from the documentation so far ... but obviously I don't have it all correct because I get the error (see below)

1) Set up environment from CMD line

```
    cordova create MyApp
    cd /MyApp
    cordova platform add android@latest
    cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
    cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
    corddova build android (after step 3 below)
```

2) Add these to index.html

A)  cdvfile: scheme to Content-Security-Policy meta tag of the index page, e.g.:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap:cdvfile:https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src
```

B)  `<img src="cdvfile:///img/logo.png" />`

C)   `<p><a href="cdvfile://video/MyVideo.mp4">Play video</a></p>`

3) Add these to config.xml

A)  `<access origin="cdvfile://*" />`

B)  `<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,assets,root" />`

The error I get on the Android when clicking on the video link is ...

```
 net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME (cdvfile:video/0001_a1.mp4)
```

===========
EDIT #1

Now trying recommendation by @DaveAlden ...  using plugin called `[cordova.plugins.diagnostic][2]` with this configuration to locate root path on ExtSD to play video BUT get the error (see below) ...

config.xml

```
 <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />

 <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="14" />

 <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="25" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />

 <plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" />
```

Index.html

```
<body>

<!-- Set up path to ExtSD on Android -->
<script>
function getSdRefAndEmbed(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getExternalSdCardDetails(function(details){
    details.forEach(function(detail){
        if(detail.type === "root"){
        cordova.file.externalSdCardRoot = detail.filePath;
        embedMedia();
        }
    });
    }, function(error){
    console.error(error);
    });
}

function embedMedia(){
    $('.extSdVideo').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', cordova.file.externalSdCardRoot + $(this).attr('href'));
    });
}

$(document).on('deviceready', getSdRefAndEmbed);
$(document).on('pageinit', embedMedia);
</script>

<!-- Play video file -->
<a class="extSdVideo" href="video/0001_a1.mp4" id="0001_a1"> a1 </a>

</body>
```

Application Error

```
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_assest/www/HHR/hhr-cm_cameroon-cm1-fra-spa/‌​‌​hhr/hhr-cm_cameroo‌​n-‌​cm1-fra-spa/vide‌​o/00‌​01_a1.mp4
```

Tried placing the `0001_a1.mp4` in either of these two directories...

```
extSDRoot/video/0001_a1.mp4
```

and/or

```
extSDRoot/www/HHR/hhr-cm_cameroon-cm1-fra-spa/‌​‌​hhr/hhr-cm_cameroo‌​n-‌​cm1-fra-spa/vide‌​o/00‌​01_a1.mp4
```

=================== EDIT #2

@DaveAlden Suggested trying these three things...

1)    Put `console.dir(details)` inside of `getExternalSdCardDetails()` to see what native paths the plugin is finding.

RESULT:  it gives the same path in the error message

```
Application Error
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
(file:///android_asset/www/hhr/cm_cameroon-cm1-fra-spa/0001_a1.mp4)
```

2) Try the [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin-example) (https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin-example) on the same device to see if the ext SD example works.

RESULT 1: The build for the example project failed...

```
BUILD FAILED Total time: 47.426 secs Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: F:\DIAGNOSTIC_WORKING\cordova-diagnostic-plugin-example\plat‌​forms\android\build\ intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrievi ng parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextA ppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
```

@DaveAlden response to the Build Fail...

> You have missing/outdated Android SDK components in your build
>   environment and/or are using an outdated version of cordova-android
>   platform.  See documentation
>   (https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#building-for-android)
>   and this issue
>   (https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/161).

My Actions:

I checked the Android SDK Manager to see that all API levels were on the same level for the required products  by running this command

```
C:> Android -v

Android SDK Tool 25.2.5
SDK platform 25
Android Support Repository 46
Google Play services 39
Google Repository 45
```

I ran this command...

```
cordova platform check android
```

Got this result...

```
F:\DIAGNOSTIC_WORKING\cordova-diagnostic-plugin-example>cordova platform check android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
android @ 6.1.2; current did not install, and thus its version cannot be determined
```

**Why do I get this "current did not install"?  Could this be the issue why the diagnostic plugin is not finding the correct path for the extSD?**

I ran this command...

```
cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android@latest && cordova build android
```

**Now the Build Succeeded for Example Project!**

See screen shot of the example diagnostic app showing path to the extSD.  This path looks very different from the path I am getting when I run the diagnostic plugin in my app.

[image]

**Note the button "Write External SD File" did not write anything when pressed.  I checked with my file manager.**

The path given for the Example Project is very different for the path that the diagnostic plugin gives for my app (see mine below).  These results were from the same Galaxy S7.

```
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_assest/www/HHR/hhr-cm_cameroon-cm1-fra-spa/‌​‌​hhr/hhr-cm_cameroo‌​n-‌​cm1-fra-spa/vide‌​o/00‌​01_a1.mp4
```

I ran this command for my app but no change ...

```
cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android@latest && cordova build android
```

3) @DaveAlden suggested running a debug using Chrome... I'll do that next.

Found this...
[image]

============= **EDIT 3 SUCCESSFULLY played video from extSD using cordova-diagnostic-plugin**

Here's how...

The final hurdle was that because I have an Android 6+ phone I had to also add a function to check for run time permission to read the extSD. The code kept bombing with the error show in Edit #2 (see above) like it was trying to see an internal path.  Once I added the function to check for run time permission it finally gave the correct external path.  Hint ... it is not enough to just provide the permission in the manifest.  You can read about it here.  Thanks @DaveAlden for your example project!

```
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin-android-runtime-example
```

> **Android runtime permissions**
>
> Android 6 / API 23 introduces the concept of runtime permissions. Similar to >iOS, certain "dangerous" permissions must be requested at runtime in addition >to being listed in the Android manifest.
>
> Runtime permissions only apply if the device/emulator the app is running on has >Android 6.0 or above AND the app is built using API 23 or higher. For Cordova, >this means using the Cordova Android platform version 5.0.0 or above. If the >app is built with version 4.x or below (API 22 or below), runtime permissions >do not apply - all permissions are granted at installation time.

Add to Config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="*" />
<plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" version="*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" version="*" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />


<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thanks to @DaveAlden for this code... I only added the function to check the run time read permission.  Dave you should just add this code for reading media files from the extSD to your project example so you don't have to help the next person as much as you did me. :)

Add to Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * 'self' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

<h3>Play video and img file</h3>

<img class="extSdImg" src="img/image1.png"/>
<img class="extSdImg" src="img/image2.png"/>

<p>
<a class="extSdVideo" href="video/video1.mp4">Play video</a>
</p>

<p>
<a class="extSdVideo" href="video/video2.mp4">Play video</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Add to Index.js

```
function authorizerequestExtSD() {
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestExternalStorageAuthorization(function(status){
    console.log("Successfully requested external storage authorization: authorization was " + status);
    checkState();
    getSdRefAndEmbed();
               }, function(error){
     console.error(error);
    });
}

function getSdRefAndEmbed(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getExternalSdCardDetails(function(details){
    details.forEach(function(detail){
           if(detail.type === "root"){
          cordova.file.externalSdCardRoot = detail.filePath;
          embedMedia();
          }
    });
        }, function(error){
            console.error(error);
    });
}

function embedMedia(){
    $('.extSdImg').each(function(){
           $(this).attr('src', cordova.file.externalSdCardRoot + $(this).attr('src'));
    });
    $('.extSdVideo').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('href', cordova.file.externalSdCardRoot + $(this).attr('href'));
    });
}

$(document).on('deviceready', authorizerequestExtSD);
$(document).on('pageinit', embedMedia);
```

Add local file copy of jQuery (found one in this project https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin-example):

```
jquery-2.1.3.min.js
```

Comment: I guess you may have to use cordova media plugn in this case. Check out this sample - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not going to work: `cdvfile://` is an internal pseudo-protocol defined by cordova where the first part of the path defines an internal reference point (`cdvfile://localhost/persistent|temporary|another-fs-root*/path/to/file`) whereas 2B and 2C are defining paths as if relative to the root of the external SD card root.

Note that [cordova-plugin-media](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media) will not help you, since it's only for playing audio and does not itself resolve file locations.

If your media files are on an external **removable** SD card (e.g. in Samsung Galaxy devices), `cordova-plugin-file` does not provide a reference to access this location. The "external" references used by cordova-plugin-file (e.g. `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory`) actually point to an internal memory location - `/scard/`. This is because not all devices have removable external SD cards (e.g. Google Nexus) so `/sdcard` is an "emulated" storage location which is guaranteed to exist on all Android devices.

If you wish to read files from the external **removable** SD card, you can do so using [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) to obtain a valid filepath reference to the external SD card root. Note that this will need to by done dynamically in JS as opposed to hardcoding static paths in HTML:

`index.html`

```
<body>
    <img class="extSdImg" src="img/image1.png"/>
    <img class="extSdImg" src="img/image2.png"/>
    <p><a class="extSdVideo" href="video/video1.mp4">Play video</a></p>
    <p><a class="extSdVideo" href="video/video2.mp4">Play video</a></p>
</body>
```

`index.js`

```
function getSdRefAndEmbed(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getExternalSdCardDetails(function(details){
    details.forEach(function(detail){
        if(detail.type === "root"){
        cordova.file.externalSdCardRoot = detail.filePath;
        embedMedia();
        }
    });
    }, function(error){
    console.error(error);
    });
}

function embedMedia(){
    $('.extSdImg').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', cordova.file.externalSdCardRoot + $(this).attr('src'));
    });
    $('.extSdVideo').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', cordova.file.externalSdCardRoot + $(this).attr('href'));
    });
}

$(document).on('deviceready', getSdRefAndEmbed);
$(document).on('pageinit', embedMedia);
```

Comment: you can use cordova-plugin-file plugin to obtain the pathto sdcard.I have created the example to display images using the plugin [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41548262/refreshing-a-particular-div-content-using-javascript-jquery/41914653#41914653)

Comment: @taranjeetsapra you cannot use cordova-plugin-file to obtain a path to an **external removable SD card** on Android (e.g. `/storage/4975-1401`, `/storage/extSdCard` ) - it just references the "internal" SD card e.g. `/storage/emulated/0/`

Comment: Could the js to find the path just be run in the header once and passed by variable into the href like so... `<a href="javascript:cordova.file.externalSdCardRoot='PathToExtSDroot/' + 'video/MyVideo.mp4'">Play video</a>`

Javascript :  `cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getExternalSdCardDetails(function(details){
    details.forEach(function(detail){
        if(detail.type === "root"){
            cordova.file.externalSdCardRoot = detail.filePath;
          }`

Comment: Pardon my js... I am not a programmer!

Comment: No that will not work. Cordova loads the JS elements of plugins dynamically at runtime so those functions won't exist when the html is parsed. You need to wait for the `deviceready` event.

Comment: Its not very practical to rewrite all the hrefs 1000's in js.   Is there a way JS to pass the path variable to the HTML via writing it to a persistent stored variable in the cordova space?   I can have my opening page find and write the path to that var and it will be ready when the page that needs it is opened??  If all pages are parsed at app start... then once app starts again.

Comment: this simply requires some dynamic HTML. There are many ways to do it, but I have updated the example code in my answer to give one I would use: insert the media links into the HTML as relative links to the SD card root. Then when the deviceready event fires, get the external SD card path and augment the links in the page with it. If you use a framework to dynamically load pages (e.g. Ionic) then use the page initialisation event to augment subsequent pages once they are loaded into the DOM.

Comment: Thank you Dave!  Here is the resulting error... `Application Error  net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_assest/www/PathOnextSD/video.mp4)`  Not sure why it put a www on the front and why it thinks this is an android_asset??

Comment: Thank you Dave!  Here is the resulting error... `Application Error  net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_assest/www/HHR/hhr-cm_cameroon-cm1-fra-spa/hhr/hhr-cm_cameroon-cm1-fra-spa/video/0001_a1.mp4)`  The path I have on the extSD is `hhr/hhr-cm_cameroon-cm1-fra-spa/video/0001_a1.mp4`       And the path I gave in the html was the same.  So it must be adding both together.  So I will try taking out one and see what it does.

Comment: well it is still not finding the file on the extSD.... Here is the error... `Application Error net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_assest/www/HHR/hhr-cm_cameroon-cm1-fra-spa/‌​hhr/hhr-cm_cameroon-‌​cm1-fra-spa/video/00‌​01_a1.mp4)`  Is it really looking on the extSD???  Where do i need to put the files on the extSD according to that error message?

Comment: @DaveAlden see EDIT #1 to my question above.  Did I do something wrong?  Maybe I did not pick up the correct branch of the plugin when I added this to my config.xml??? `<plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" />`  or I need to do something different when I target such a low level like this??? `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="14" />`

Comment: 1) Put `console.dir(details)` inside of `getExternalSdCardDetails()` to see what native paths the plugin is finding. 2) Try the [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin-example) on the same device to see if the ext SD example works. 3) Connect remote debug session using Chrome DevTools and place breakpoints in the code to see exactly what the variable values are.

Comment: @DaveAlden I got an error on running your example project... `BUILD FAILED

Total time: 47.426 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
F:\DIAGNOSTIC_WORKING\cordova-diagnostic-plugin-example\platforms\android\build\
intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrievi
ng parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextA
ppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.`

Comment: `F:\DIAGNOSTIC_WORKING\cordova-diagnostic-plugin-example\platforms\android\build\
intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrievi
ng parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextA
ppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`

Comment: `* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.E
xecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Ownerc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-
tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.`

Comment: @BobAchgill You have missing/outdated Android SDK components in your build environment and/or are using an outdated version of cordova-android platform. See [the documentation](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#building-for-android) and [this issue](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/161)

Comment: @DaveAlden See Edits #2 to my main question for results from trying your   suggestions 1 and 2.

Comment: @DaveAlden ... and 3.

Comment: @DaveAlden <br/>
Your suggestions 1 and 3 don't seem to possible because Chrome does not start debugging until the page is up.  <br/>
Your suggestion to run the project example works fine but it uses a button to begin the process to get the path to the extSD.  <br/>
Do you have any other thoughts?<br/>
Does the code you provided run OK for you? <br/>
Thank you for your help! <br/>
<br/>
---

Comment: Maybe it would help to put the second function nested in the first??? ... so they get processed together on `deviceready` event.

Comment: Thanks Dave... see my Edit 3 in my question.  The issue why the code you gave me was not finding the path to the extSD was that it needed a run time permission.  I added a function for doing so from your example project and it now finds the extSD path!  Thank you!  You should add the code sample you gave me to your project example for the next person who needs to read media from the extSD using cordova-diagnostic-plugin